# How to search multiple columns with one search using multiple inputs

Tags: php, mysql, html

here is my php code:

```
if (($_REQUEST['Search']) || ($_REQUEST['CSV'])){
$street = $_REQUEST['street'];
$zip = $_REQUEST['zip'];
$city = $_REQUEST['city'];
$type = $_REQUEST['type'];
if ($_REQUEST['street']){
    $q = " SELECT * FROM $usertable WHERE address LIKE '%$street%' ORDER BY address ";
}
if ($_REQUEST['zip']){
    $q = " SELECT * FROM $usertable WHERE zip LIKE '%$zip%' ORDER BY address ";
}
if ($_REQUEST['city']){
    $q = " SELECT * FROM $usertable WHERE city LIKE '%$city%' ORDER BY address ";
}
$qu = mysql_query($q);
```

Here is my html:

```
<form action="" method="post">
Zip:<input name="zip" type="text" />
Street:<input name="street" type="text" />
City:<input name ="city" type="text" />
Type:<select id="type" name="type">
<option value="Invasion">Invasion</option>
<option value="Burglary">Burglary</option>
<option value="Theft">Theft</option>
</select>
<input name="Search" type="submit" value="Search" />
<input name="CSV" type="submit" value="Get CSV" />
</form>
```

What I'm trying to do is have my site searchable using any combination of city zip or street.  I'm sure I'll have to concatenate or something, but as a backyard programmer I'm a bit stumped.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To get it all in 1 query (not tested);

```
    <?php

    $q = " SELECT * FROM ". $usertable ." WHERE 1 %s ORDER BY address ";

    if ($_REQUEST['street']){
        $where[] = " address LIKE '%".$street."%' ";
    }
    if ($_REQUEST['zip']){
        $where[] = " zip LIKE '%".$zip."%' ";
    }
    if ($_REQUEST['city']){
        $where[] = " city LIKE '%".$city."%' ";
    }

    $q = sprintf($q, implode(" AND ", $where));

    echo $q;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample of how you can generate the query search based on the fields you define.
The search will be performed only on the fields that have a value and the query is safe (the values are escaped so you don't need to worry about SQL Injection).

I added comments in the code

```
<?php
if (($_REQUEST['Search']) || ($_REQUEST['CSV'])){

$conditions = array();
// define the fields that are searchable (we assumed that the table field names match the form input names)
$search_fields = array('street', 'zip', 'city', 'type');
foreach($search_fields as $field) {
    // if the field is set and it is not empty
    if (isset($_REQUEST[$field]) && strlen($_REQUEST[$field]) > 0){
        // escape the value
        $conditions[] = "`$field` LIKE '%". mysql_real_escape($field) ."%'";
    }
}

$q = "SELECT * FROM $usertable ";

// if there are conditions defined
if(count($conditions) > 0)
{
    // concatenate them and append to the query
    // we use operator AND to retrieve results that match all defined criteria
    $q .= "WHERE ".  implode(" AND ", $conditions);
}

$qu = mysql_query($q);
```